# Using Bokeh chart interactions in Jupyter / IPython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh

I have a Bokeh chart in a Jupyter notebook, and I want to run custom Python whenever the Bokeh selection changes.  It is very easy to run custom Javascript whenever the Bokeh selection changes using a source change callback, but I have no way to trigger Jupyter to respond to the event.

I think it is possible but poorly documented (see http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) to run a separate Bokeh server to receive the events.  I want to avoid running a separate Bokeh server since the Jupyter server is already running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look at holoview. 
It is design for this. You can choose between different renderers : matpotlib, bokeh, plotly.

You can either use their methodology for simple plots or if it is more specific you can [run bokeh apps](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html).

As you can see almost all examples of bokeh are ported to [holoviews](http://build.holoviews.org/)
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a two-way communication between Bokeh object and Jupyter: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/jupyter.html#notebook-handles

1. Import standard functions and `push_notebook()`
2. Create some plots and pass `notebook_handle=True` to `show()`
3. Check that the handle is associated with the output cell
4. Update some properties of the plot, then call `push_notebook()` with the handle
5. Note that the output cell has changed (without being re-executed)

You might have to poll the variable you want to catch changing, as this does not look like an event handler, just mutual exposure.